# This function returns null instead of the right value to the zoom parameter in CameraPosition and I can't figure it out

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a function that calculates the amount of CameraPosition zoom required depending on the distance between 2 Google map markers. The method specified in the CameraPosition zoom parameter (zoomIn) is called which in turn calls another async method that returns the distance between the two points (getDistance). Both methods run properly but zoomIn always returns null despite the print statement showing the right calculated value. Is this a synchronization issue?

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: GoogleMap(
            onMapCreated: addMarkers,
            cameraTargetBounds: CameraTargetBounds(createTargetBounds()),
            initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                target:
                    LatLng((currentLocation.latitude + latitudesArr[selectedDestination]) / 2,
                          (currentLocation.longitude + longitudesArr[selectedDestination]) / 2),
                zoom: zoomIn(bounds: createTargetBounds(), padding: 200.0)),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  double zoomIn({LatLngBounds bounds, double padding}) {
    double zoom;
    getDistance(bounds).then((double distance){
      print('Distance: $distance');
      if (distance > 200){
        zoom = 16.0;
      } else {
        zoom = 18.0;
      }
      print ('Zoom: $zoom');
    });
    return zoom;
  }

  Future<double> getDistance(LatLngBounds bounds) async {
    double distance = await Geolocator().distanceBetween(
        bounds.southwest.latitude,
        bounds.southwest.longitude,
        bounds.northeast.latitude,
        bounds.northeast.longitude);
    print('Distance: $distance');
    return distance;
  }


The zoomIn function correctly populates the zoom variable with 16.0 or 18.0 depending on the distance between the two markers. However, null is always returned.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured that the correct way of doing this is to hard-code the zoom value when the Google map widget is declared, for example:

```
class MapState extends State<MapRoute> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
          GoogleMap(
            onMapCreated: addMarkers,
            myLocationEnabled: true,
            cameraTargetBounds: CameraTargetBounds(createTargetBounds()),
            initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                target:
                    LatLng((currentLocation.latitude + latitudesArr[selectedDestination]) / 2,
                          (currentLocation.longitude + longitudesArr[selectedDestination]) / 2),
                zoom: 18.0),
          ),
```

Then, in this example, on the `addMarkers` method, the following code will wait until `GeoLocator` returns a distance and only then it can be determined the desired level of zoom. After that is only a matter of calling the map controller's `moveCamera(CameraUpdate.zoomTo(zoom))` as follows:

```
    await Geolocator().distanceBetween(
        bounds.southwest.latitude,
        bounds.southwest.longitude,
        bounds.northeast.latitude,
        bounds.northeast.longitude)
        .then((distance) {
          print('The Distance: $distance');
          double zoom;
          if (distance > 300) {
            zoom = 17.0;
          } else if (distance > 100){
            zoom = 18.0;
          } else {
            zoom = 19.0;
          }
          print ('Zoom: $zoom');
          controller.moveCamera(CameraUpdate.zoomTo(zoom));
        });
```